# Extracting geometric forms with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I running a video in which I want to detect 3 geometric forms triangle circle and pentagon, and nothing else, here a frame from this video and the result that I get :

[image: source]

the correct result

[image: correct result]

One bad result from many.

[image: Bad result]

and here's my code:

```
img =src;
cv::Moments mom;
cv::Mat result(img.size(),CV_8U,cv::Scalar(255));
cv::threshold(img,img,127,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
cv::findContours(img,contours,/*hiararchy,*/CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
for ( int i=0; i<contours.size();i++){
    cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]),approx,(cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]),true)*.02),true);
switch(approx.size()){

            case 8: // should be a circle 
                cv::minEnclosingCircle(cv::Mat(contours[i]),center,radius);
                cv::circle(src,cv::Point(center),static_cast<int> (radius),cv::Scalar(255,255,0),3,3);
                mom= cv::moments(cv::Mat(contours[i]));
            // draw mass center
            cv::circle(result,
            // position of mass center converted to integer
                cv::Point(mom.m10/mom.m00,mom.m01/mom.m00),
            2,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);// draw black dot 
                break;

case 3: // should be a triangle 
                poly.clear();
                    cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]),poly,
                    5, // accuracy of the approximation
                    true); // yes it is a closed shape
                    // Iterate over each segment and draw it
                    itp= poly.begin();
                while (itp!=(poly.end()-1)) {
                    cv::line(src,*itp,*(itp+1),cv::Scalar(0,255,255),2);
                    ++itp;
                    }
                // last point linked to first point
                cv::line(src,*(poly.begin()),*(poly.end()-1),cv::Scalar(100,255,100),2);
                mom= cv::moments(cv::Mat(contours[i]));
                // draw mass center
                cv::circle(result,
                // position of mass center converted to integer
                cv::Point(mom.m10/mom.m00,mom.m01/mom.m00),
                2,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);// draw black dot 
                    break;
            case 5 :// should be a pentagon
                poly.clear(); 
                    cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]),poly,
                    5, // accuracy of the approximation
                    true); // yes it is a closed shape
                // Iterate over each segment and draw it
                itp= poly.begin();
                while (itp!=(poly.end()-1)) {
                    cv::line(src,*itp,*(itp+1),cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
                    ++itp;
                }
                // last point linked to first point
                    cv::line(src,*(poly.begin()),*(poly.end()-1),cv::Scalar(255,0,0),2);
                    mom= cv::moments(cv::Mat(contours[i]));
            // draw mass center
            cv::circle(result,
            // position of mass center converted to integer
                cv::Point(mom.m10/mom.m00,mom.m01/mom.m00),
            2,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);// draw black dot 
                    break;

            default : 
                contours[i].clear();
        }
// iterate over all contours
        int j = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size();i++) {
            if ( !contours[i].empty()){
            // compute all moments

            j++; // At the end  j should be 3 
    }
            if(j ==3 ){
        cv::drawContours(result,contours,-1, // draw all contours 
            cv::Scalar(0), // in black
            2); // with a thickness of 2
        cv::imshow("result",result);
            }
}   std::cout<<j<<std::endl;


    return j;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this ? 
thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could combine your approach with a corner detector (also part of opencv) and add that as a second stage to your classifier? (i.e. only passing shapes that have 0, 3 or 5 corners )

Comment: Alternatively a more general approach would be to use a cascade-classifier approach, which requires that you train the classifier with positive and negative samples until the desired level of discrimination is reached.

Comment: @mutzmatron thanks for your answer , I can't try the second suggestion  because I work with the result in other classes, but the first sounds good , but to do that ? thanks in advance

Comment: opencv already has corner detectors (such as [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornerharris)) - corners can be associated with the shapes you already detect (check to see if they lie on the shape (or within some tolerance) - then only accept shapes with 0, 3 or 5 associated corners.

Comment: if you read my code the switch case statement is checking number of corners !

Comment: Not exactly; your code checks the number of straight lines that approximate the outlines of the shapes (e.g. you used 8 for circle). Instead of approximating the shapes with polygons, I'm suggesting you run a corner detector to detect corners on the objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the geometric shapes are always located within such a checkerboard pattern and the shapes have same size and orientation within that pattern all the time, I would:

1. detect the checkerboard pattern.
2. remove the perspective distortion with a homography
3. scale and rotate so that the checkerboard pattern is axis aligned and at a given scale
4. use chamfer matching to detect the specified shapes.